# Самый быстрый (короткий) способ крашнуть вкладку

Tags: javascript, jquery, framework, webbrowser, браузер

Как, используя минимум символов, уронить вкладку браузера / уйти в вечный цикл или рекурсию или что-то в этом духе?

Предлагайте свои варианты на чистом `js` или с использованием фреймворков.

Answer (score 6):

Или такой цикл например :D

```js
while(1);
```

Comment: у хрома это не вызовет крэш вкладки, а только лишь предупреждение о долго выоплняющемся скрипте...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ по вопросу не совсем понятно что требуется именно краш как таковой, я читаю как требуется краш/бесконечный цикл/рекурсия/etc.

Comment: Ну да, формально Вы правы

Answer (score 4):

Один из самых коротких способов открыл для себя недавно. Он на `jquery`.

```js
$($)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Спасибо всем, кто принял участие. Очень занятно было наблюдать за комментариями.

Comment: На `jquery` не совсем честно :)

Answer (score 3):

19 символов

```js
for(let a;;a+=" ");
```

Comment: Тогда уж `for(a='';a+=' ';);` 18 символов) Правда, в strict mode не работает

Comment: @andreymal мой тоже странно себе ведет, сначала вкладка, теперь перестала

Comment: Или `for(;;URL+=' ');` 16 символов за счёт переиспользования существующей переменной, и в strict mode работает (а если есть window.$, то и в 14 символов сожмётся)

Comment: @andreymal я тоже уже поковырялся в глобальном объекте =)

Comment: @andreymal на 1 символ короче - сделать итерацию в теле цикла, можно ; в конце не писать будет

Comment: а зачем переменные вообще? `for(;;);`

Comment: он просто зависнет тогда и выпадет окно о долгом выполнении, а так грустная рожа появляется

Comment: @Grundy без переменных неинтересно, а с ними у меня вот Firefox продолжает старательно пожирать оперативу даже после закрытия вкладки, приходится целиком перезапускать)

Comment: @Grundy хуже того, у меня даже новые вкладки перестают открываться))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а если так? `(function a(){a()}())` :)

Comment: ну так просто call stack, со стрелочной тогда уж

Comment: Или ещё вот так `for(;;)URL+=$` 13 символов

Comment: (чёртов Firefox, я проверял это в режиме инкогнито, а он после закрытия окна всё равно всю память сожрал!)

Comment: @andreymal это его фирменная тема =)

Answer (score 1):

Немного поигрался в консоли, написал банальное зацикливание. Пару секунд и страница мертвая. Я так понимаю заканчивается слишком большой объект получается.

```
function crash(){
let i = 1;
let a = {};
while (i > 0){
        a[i] = i++;
        console.log(a); 
    }
}
crash()
```

Comment: Чет многовато кода, чтобы просто уйти в бесконечный цикл

Comment: Учиться учиться и учиться еще

Answer (score 1):

Столько вариантов, предложу и я интересный)

```
while(true) {
   window.open();
}


for(;;) {}
```